# Create a View of Books

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I'm using the core Book module for organizing meeting notes and documentation. How do I create a list of books with the views module? That is, I'd like a list of *only* the top-level Books, not all the book pages.

An example of what I want in core is at `admin/content/book` which looks like this:

[image]

Thus far, all I've been able to get is a hierarchical list of books *and* all book pages. Current view:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Create a taxonomy term and defined in your content type
- Use [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) or [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) to create new term when you add new book "book name is taxonomy term"
- Create a view using taxonomy term and select those terms whose parents has value = 0

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm looking for a solution that uses the core Book module though, I've edited the question to be more explicit. With your answer, I'd have to change the hierarchy in two places, the Book outline and the Taxonomy.